"android:exported" Android 12 on Google Play console
i get "android:exported" error when try to load .aab on google play console. This is my manifest.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="50700" android:versionName="5.7.0" package="com.t4t.bconn" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="false" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" />
        <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler" />
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.t4t.bconn" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.t4t.bconn.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.t4t.bconn.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>

Even though I have added the 'exported:true' directive everywhere in mnaifest.xml
i keep getting the error 'exported:true' that is preventing me from publishing to Android 12.

Does this answer your question? Apps targeting Android 12 and higher required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` [Cordova]
